# Why UIScrollView's scrolling triggers layoutSubViews method in iOS 4.3 but not in 5.0 & above?

Tags: ios5, uiscrollview, ios4, layoutsubviews

I have customized UIView to create a custom UI component.

The hierarchy of views are this way.

----Custom UIView

----------------UIScrollView

-----------------------------Sub Views in ScrollView

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if(self){

//Allocation and Initialization of ScrollView
//...
[super addSubView:scrollView];

}
return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    DLog(@"%@",[NSThread callStackSymbols]);
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self reloadData];

}

//This method can be used to reload the entire control
-(void)reloadData{
//Reload the subviews of control
}
```

When ever the scroll view is scrolled, the layoutSubviews method gets called in iOS version 4.3. But in case of versions above 4.3 (5.0 , 6.0) this event handler does not get called.

In my use case, I do not wanted the layoutsubviews to get called.

How can I ensure that I have a scroll view when scrolled that does not trigger the layoutsubviews method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is below:

1. Add a container UIView (for reference ScrollViewHolder)on top of the customized view
2. Then add the UIScrollView on the view ScrollViewHolder.

----Custom UIView

----------------Another UIView

-------------------------------UIScrollView

--------------------------------------------Sub Views in ScrollView

The init method is now changed to the following:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if(self){

//Allocation and Initialization of Container View

[super addSubView:ScrollViewHolder];
//Allocation and Initialization of ScrollView
//...
[ScrollViewHolder addSubView:scrollView];

}
return self;
}
```